# Visual Studio 2022 - hide/disable debugging terminal windows in NET 6 + Angular project

Tags: angular, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

Is there any option to move all debug consoles in Visual Studio 2022 to Output section on the bottom? There is one console for backend (API) and one for frontend (npm start). This is very annoying. Besides, the same output is shown in both backend console and VS Output section (except angular npm start). What's the point of that?

I did setup the `Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console`, but the npm with Angular is not closing. I think there should be an option to run both "consoles" in VS Output.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Latest 2022 has terminal built in for API, but frontend is still opening in new console window.

Comment: Yes, I have same experience

Comment: And that is probably maximum what Microsoft can do with this type of projects